# Select in SQL from 2 tables calculating average

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables like that:

Student

```
ID | Name   | Age

1  | Jonh   | 20   
2  | Smit   | 19   
3  | David  | 28   
4  | Simon  | 18   
5  | Kate   | 17   
6  | Marry  | 20
```

Rating

```
Studen_ID | mark  

1         |  10   
1         |  5
2         |  7
3         |  9
3         |  8
```

I want to Select "Student" with Ratting" and show "Reporting" like that:

```
Reporting
ID | Name   | Age | avg_mark

1  | Jonh   | 20  | 15 
2  | Smit   | 19  | 7
3  | David  | 28  | 17
4  | Simon  | 18  | null
5  | Kate   | 17  | null
6  | Marry  | 20  | null
```

Please help me to do that. I am so stupid ><

Thanks
Nguyen

Comment: Google "SQL JOIN".  Its been answered many, many times here and many other places.

Answer (score 1):

This query gets the students that have ratings, showing their name and average mark. If you want to show all of them regardless if the have or not rating, change the `INNER` by `LEFT`.

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.age, AVG(r.mark) AS avg_mark
  FROM student s
  INNER JOIN rating r ON s.id = r.student_id
  GROUP BY s.id, s.name, s.age
```

Comment: Did you actually try this? It won't run as you need to include name and age in the group by clause too, and also it will exclude student that lack ratings.

Comment: Yes, you are right since the tag is SqlServer, in Mysql works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select id, name, age, sum(mark) as avg_mark from student
left join  rating on student.id = rating.student_id
group by student.id, student.name, student.age
```

But note that in your example the avg_mark is actually the sum, not the average. If you want average (rounded) you should use `avg(mark)` instead like this:

```
select id, name, age, avg(mark) as avg_mark from student
left join  rating on student.id = rating.student_id
group by student.id, student.name, student.age
```

Sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fcd2a/9) for both queries.

Comment: @user1186850 Happy to help. If my answer solver your problem, you should consider marking it as accepted.